# Do multiple .fetch() promises

Tags: javascript, promise, blob, fetch

I want to ***fetch multiple images  and turn them in blob***. I'm a newbie about promises, I've tried but I can't get through.

Here below, a single `.fetch()` promise

```
fetch('http://cors.io/?u=http://alistapart.com/d/_made/d/ALA350_appcache_300_960_472_81.jpg')
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.blob();
    })
    .then(function(myBlob) {
        var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
        document.getElementById('myImage').src = objectURL;
    });
```

Now multiple `.fetch()` promise (don't work)

```
var promises = [];

for (var i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    promises.push(fetch(values[i]));
}

Promise
    .all(promises)
    .then(function(response) {
        for (var i = response.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            return response[i].blob();
        }
    })
    .then(function(blob) {
        console.log(blob.length); //undefined !!!
        for (var i = blob.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            console.log(blob[i]);
            lcl_images[i].value = URL.createObjectURL(blob[i]);
            document.getElementById(lcl_images[i].id).src = objectURL;
        }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Comment: So what does the `.blob()` method return, a `blob` or a `promise`?

Comment: .blob() returns a blob(), but if  you're doing multiple promise, you have to `return Promise.all(blobs)` in `.then(response)`. After this, in `.then(blob)` -> blob is array of blob objects

Comment: OK, so if `.blob()` is synchronous, then you don't need two .thens. `Promise.all(promises).then(function(responses) {...}).catch(...);`will do the job without ever needing to create an array of blobs.

Comment: if you try yourself this won't work, I'm a newbie about promise. I've tried several times doing what you said, but you have to return the promise `response[i].blob()` and in the next `.then` you'll have the blob object.

Comment: I'll write an answer for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are returning from the then handler after first response, instead what you need to do is to return the list of blobs:

```
Promise
.all(promises)
.then(function(response) {
    // CHANGED HERE
    var blobPromises = [];
    for (var i = response.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        blobPromises.push(response[i].blob());
    }
    return Promise.all(blobPromises);
})
.then(function(blob) {
    console.log(blob.length);
    for (var i = blob.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        lcl_images[i].value = URL.createObjectURL(blob[i]);
        document.getElementById(lcl_images[i].id).src = objectURL;
    }
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: I've edited your solution and added console.log(), you can clearly see the problem: I don't have blob objects in the blob promise, this is why it raises the error: `TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.(…)`

Comment: When you `return blobs`, you end up with `blobs` in the next function, not `blob`. `blob.length` is undefined because it's an array of blobs, not a single blob.

Comment: Also in this case, your `blobs` are actually an array of _promises_ for blobs, meaning you need to `return Promise.all(blobs)`. Really you should rename that `blobs` to `blobPromises` or something.

Answer (score 7):

It is a general rule that a wholly synchronous intermediate step in the success path of a promise chain can be amalgamated with the next step, allowing one `then()` to be omitted from the chain.

*There is actually a proviso on that statement, involving intermediate catches, but it will suffice for this answer.*

So, if the `.blob()` method is geuinely synchronous (it returns a value), only one `.then()` is required, not two.

Here are two approaches, both of which exploit [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and both should work (though they will differ under error conditions):

**1. Simple `.map()` with detail in `Promise.all()`**

```
var promises = values.reverse().map(fetch); // you may need .reverse(), maybe not. I'm not 100% sure.

return Promise.all(promises).then(function(responses) {
    responses.forEach(function(r, i) {
        var imageObj = lcl_images[i],
            element = document.getElementById(imageObj.id);
        imageObj.value = URL.createObjectURL(r.blob());
        if(element) { //safety
            element.src = imageObj.value;
        }
    });
    return responses; // here, return whatever you want to be made available to the caller.
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

If you prefer, you can write :

```
return Promise.all(values.reverse().map(fetch)).then(function(responses) {
    // ...
});
```

**2. Detail in `.map()` followed a simple `Promise.all()`**

```
var promises = values.reverse().map(function(val, i) {
    return fetch(val).then(function(result) {
        var imageObj = lcl_images[i],
            element = document.getElementById(imageObj.id);
        imageObj.value = URL.createObjectURL(result.blob());
        if(element) { //safety
            element.src = imageObj.value;
        }
        return result; // here, return whatever you want to be made available to the caller.
    });
});

return Promise.all(promises).catch(function(error) { // return a promise to the caller
    console.log(error);
});
```

Notes:

- (1) will fail completely if any one `fetch()` fails.
- (2) will perform all the `imageObj.value ...` and `element.src = ...` stuff for all *successful* fetches even if one or more `fetch()...` fails. Any single failure will cause `Promise.all(promises)` to return a rejected promise.
- (1) or (2) may be more appropriate depending on what you want.
- There are other error handling possibilities.
- If neither approach works, then the most reasonable explanation would be that the `.blob()` method returns a promise, not a value.

Comment: If that's the API being called, then it's cool. Any object other than a promise is OK here.